# Est-ce qu'il y a un autre mot « win » que n'est pas « victoire »

Tags: synonymes

I'm trying to translate a sentence from English to French which uses the words "win" and "victory" independently. I was wondering if there is another word besides *victoire* in French which would be the equivalent of "win" in English.

Merci beaucoup!

Comment: How does the English sentence differentiate the two senses? That will help determine which pair of French terms might capture the distinction.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I meant the use of "win" and "victory" as two separate nouns in a sentence, along the lines of "he claimed the win, the victory he was after."

Comment: Ah okay, so they're synonymous -- if anything we might want the second to be the slightly more literary or dramatic term :)

Answer (score 3):

While repeating words is generally avoided in French, this is a case where it can be done without being frowned upon:

> Il a revendiqué la victoire, victoire à laquelle il aspirait tant.

You can also easily avoid it:

> Il a revendiqué la victoire qu'il ambitionnait.

Otherwise, there are a few words that might work (succès, consécration, première place, médaille d'or, honneur, conquête, sacre... ) but more context is required to find which ones fit. e.g.:

> Il a revendiqué la victoire, cette médaille d'or qu'il désirait tant.

Answer (score 1):

— Utilisez [Deepl](https://www.deepl.com/translator), tapez *win* dans le cadre de gauche et vérifiez la langue proposée,

— Sélectionnez *français* dans le cadre droite,

— Cliquez avec le bouton droit sur le mot proposé, et voici le résultat :

> conquérir ...
>
> victoire ...
>
> gagner ...
>
> triompher ...
>
> capter ...
>
> remporter ...
>
> gain ...
>
> vaincre ...
>
> reconquérir ...
>
> gagnez ...
>
> capter l'attention ...
>
> obtenir ...
>
> triomphe ...
>
> réussir ...
>
> gagne ...
>
> acquérir ...
>
> obtenir la victoire ...
>
> vainqueur ...
>
> obtenir gain de cause ...
>
> l’emporter ...
>
> s’attirer ...
>
> reconquête ...

Bienvenue dans le monde de la traduction … qui dépend du contexte !

Comment: @subsexdexter — Ce n’est pas un remède universel, mais un sacré défricheur, capable de faire le gros œuvre il vous laisse le choix des finitions. Apparemment la question venait d’un débutant en demande d’outils. *DeepL* aide beaucoup en préparant un choix de réponses et tournures en fonction des contextes possibles …  *gratuité* pour les étudiants et droit d’utilisation  pour les professionnels.

Comment: @subsexdexter — … pas d’accord, et c’est là une des richesses de *DeepL*, il n’invente rien et ne cache pas la poussière sous le tapis ni ne s’impose comme censeur/normalisateur/déité du français parfait, pour des recherches sur les emplois rares : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=livrer+la+parole&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clivrer%20la%20parole%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clivrer%20la%20parole%3B%2Cc1 → *deliver a speech*

Comment: @subsexdexter — … ce qui ne nous met pas à l’abri des anglicismes https://french.stackexchange.com/q/33748/848  :-) et c’est peut-être ce que *DeepL* devrait préciser.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
Ces deux mots sont différents: / These two words have different meaning:

> "win" usually mean "gagner" in French (which is a ***verb***)
>
> "victory" usually mean "victoire" (which is a feminine ***noun***)

Comment: *Win* est aussi un nom commun, synonyme de *victory*.

Comment: En effet mais je ne parle ici que du sens et des traductions **françaises**. Win en français n'a qu'une seule et unique traduction "Gagner" qui est un verbe.

Comment: La question porte sur *win* utilisé comme substantif. On ne peut pas répondre que le mot n'existe pas. Il existe d'ailleurs bien un déverbal de gagner en français: *la gagne*.

Comment: Vous avez effectivement raison, je n'avais pas prêté assez attention au fait que nous parlions ici de substantif.

Answer (score 0):

Une petite variante: il a crié victoire, victoire qu'il désirait (voulait) tant. Comme indiqué dans une réponse précédente, la répétition est admise dans ce cas. Crier victoire (expression courante) implique qu'on la revendique.