# « Livrer un discours » au propre pour « prononcer (un discours) » est-il un emploi fautif ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage, anglicismes

J'ai trouvé une [source](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_l&page=9Qj0yJPZhQAA.html) (mais bien une seule) crédible à l'effet que ***[livrer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/livrer) un discours*** est un emploi à éviter dans le sens de *prononcer* (un discours) ; un emploi qui ressemble à un calque de l'anglais (*to deliver a speech*). On parle d'un emploi **au propre** ici et non au figuré (*Ac.9* : À partir des sens *exposer, abandonner, soumettre à l'action, aux effets de quelque chose*, du verbe [livrer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/livrer), on l'emploie au figuré pour *faire connaître*, *révéler* : *Je livre ces quelques phrases à votre méditation, à votre sagacité. Livrer ses pensées, ses espoirs, ses impressions* [...] ; voir aussi indirectement un billet sur [*délivrer*](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/dire-ne-pas-dire/recherche?titre=livrer&rubrique=&date=&form_build_id=form-ktCfnOE8eG68bI0dQIrYRpcSd7mv3kx8Uo9bCAsmsZ0&form_id=academie_blog_search_form&op=Rechercher) et [ceci](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/12995/3177)).

Sans surprise, des pseudo-traductions contextuelles regorgent de l'emploi en question ([Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/livrer+un+discours), [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/livrer+un+discours.html)), qu'on trouve aussi évidemment dans un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=livrer%20un%20discours&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clivrer%20un%20discours%3B%2Cc0) et par l'entremise d'un moteur de recherche bien connu ([60000 résultats](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=7gtaXNbjIsWb5gLsubSgDQ&q=%22livrer%20un%20discours%22&btnK=Google%20Search&oq=%22livrer%20un%20discours%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30l2.1133.5108..5550...0.0..0.185.1752.17j4......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0i131j0j0i10j0i22i10i30.K-aB6v46FsM) et plus).

---

Peut-on confirmer ou infirmer qu'il s'agit là d'un emploi fautif, en s'appuyant sur des sources crédibles (comme des ouvrages traitant des difficultés du français/de traduction, par exemple) ; si l'emploi au propre n'était pas fautif, sur quelle extension de quel sens du verbe *livrer* (voire de *délivrer*, ou pire encore, de *to deliver*) s'appuierait-il ; combien de fois un emploi fautif doit être répété sur internet pour être accepté et devenir un usage en langue française (question rhétorique) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Livrer un discours* n'est pas idiomatique. Les expressions consacrées sont :

- **Prononcer un discours**
  et
- **Faire un discours**

Il y a aussi la plus récente *tenir un discours* mais le sens est différent (discours doit être qualifié) :

- Il tient un discours incohérent
- Il a un discours incohérent

Dans ce cas, *discours* signifie *propos*, il n'est pas forcément question d'un discours prononcé devant un auditoire, mais simplement de l'expression orale d'une personne.

On peut répondre à la question,  « que fait-il en ce moment ? »  comme ceci :

- Il prononce un discours.
- Il fait un discours.

mais difficilement comme cela :

- Il tient un discours.
- Il a un discours.

[image]

Livrer, dans le sens figuré décrit dans la question, consiste à « libérer » quelque chose de personnel caché dans son esprit. On livre ses pensées, ses impressions, un secret mais pas un discours, qui est un « produit fini ». On livre (c'est à dire on confie) quelque chose à voix basse alors qu'on prononce un discours a voix haute. *Livrer* et *discours* sont antinomiques. On pourrait en revanche *livrer à quelqu'un les grandes lignes d'un discours que l'on doit faire plus tard*.

*Délivrer un discours* (ou le *livrer* au sens propre) est de son côté indubitablement un anglicisme. Comme l'indique très bien [l'Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/delivrer-des-informations), *délivrer* a plusieurs sens en français, comme celui de rendre sa liberté à quelqu'un, accoucher une femme, ou, par extension, remettre en main propre un objet.

L'Académie conclut par :

> Rappelons donc qu’on ne délivre que des personnes ou des objets concrets et qu’il convient de ne pas ajouter à ces sens celui de « donner des informations », qui serait un anglicisme.

La première occurrence que trouve google ngrams date de 1958. Elle est assez instructive :

> Vie et Langage - Numéros 70 à 81 - Page 646
>
> Le verbe *to pronounce* ( « prononcer ») ne s'emploie pas pour traduire en anglais notre expression « prononcer un discours ». On dit dans ce cas « to deliver a speech », soit « livrer un discours ». Vous retiendrez d'ailleurs mieux cette particularité à l'aide du mot d'esprit : « The easiest way to stay awake during a speech is to deliver it ».

En français, *livrer un discours* ou *délivrer un discours* n'ont donc pas de sens (hors [anglicisme](http://chouxdesiam.canalblog.com/archives/2015/02/07/31478539.html) bien sûr), ou du moins pas celui de prononcer un discours. Les rares occurrences que les moteurs de recherche rapportent correspondent plus à un synonyme de *tenir un discours* qui ne signifie pas la même chose (***avoir** un discours* au lieu de ***faire** un discours*).

La corrélation entre les évolutions respectives de *livrer* et *tenir* un discours (en incluant les formes verbales les plus courantes) est d'ailleurs notable, ce qui peut laisser supposer un lien entre elles :

[image]

[image]

*Livrer un discours* est toutefois environ 80 fois moins fréquent que *tenir un discours*.

On peut aussi imaginer, mais c'est un peu tiré par les cheveux, que *livrer un discours* représente un porteur qui transmet à quelqu'un le discours rédigé à son attention par un « [prête-plume](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31033/n%C3%A8gre-litt%C3%A9raire) »...

Quant à savoir quand un anglicisme est suffisamment ancré dans les habitudes pour ne plus être considéré comme fautif, la réponse ne peut être que subjective.

On retrouve par exemple cet anglicisme ici :

[Huffington Post 10 décembre 2018](https://www.huffingtonpost.fr/2018/12/10/avant-le-discours-de-macron-les-gilets-jaunes-affichent-leur-scepticisme_a_23613912/)

> Après un quatrième épisode de fronde des gilets jaunes, Emmanuel Macron a tenté de reprendre la main en recevant ce lundi 10 décembre les corps intermédiaires avant de **livrer** une allocution exceptionnelle à "la Nation" depuis l'Élysée à 20 heures.

Answer (score 0):

« [Livrer un discours](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=livrer+un+discours&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clivrer%20un%20discours%3B%2Cc0) » est employé de façon assez courante depuis les années 60, bien que rare en comparaison avec « prononcer un discours » ; sa fréquence d'utilisation est cependant à peu près la moitié de celle de [« adresser un discours »](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adresser+un+discours%2Clivrer+un+discours&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadresser%20un%20discours%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clivrer%20un%20discours%3B%2Cc0). « [To deliver a speech](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+deliver+a+speech&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20deliver%20a%20speech%3B%2Cc0) » est courant en anglais depuis à peu près 1790, et donc il est plus que probable que l'acception figuré de ce verbe dans ce contexte provienne directement de l'anglais. Comme on peut constater que la fréquence d'usage en français de nos jours est approximativement 10 % de la fréquence d'usage de l'expression correspondante en anglais, laquelle est courante, on est en droit de conclure que cette expression est assez solidement introduite dans le français. De plus on constate une grimpée en flèche dans la fréquence et il n'y a aucune raison qui laisse penser que quelque chose pourrait y mettre un un terme.