# Peut-on « livrer un discours » au sens de « confier » ou au sens figuré de « faire connaître, révéler » : exemples ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage

Peut-on *[livrer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/livrer) un **discours*** au sens de *confier* (comme livrer *un secret, ses impressions* ; TLFi) ou au sens figuré du verbe [*livrer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/livrer) (*faire connaître, révéler*... *livrer ses pensées, ses espoirs, ses impressions* ; Ac.9). Peut-on présenter des exemples (en littérature etc.) où ce serait indubitablement le cas (uniquement en ce qui a trait à un *discours*) ?

---

> TLFi (livrer) :
>   3. Abandonner, confier (à quelqu'un).
>  [...]
>  c) [L'obj. désigne un inanimé abstr.] Confier. *Livrer ses impressions, un
>   secret. Certains (...) rougissaient de livrer leur préférence*
>   (Lacretelle, *Silbermann*, 1922, p. 89). *Marthe (...) ne livre qu'une
>   faible part de ce qu'elle pense* (Bosco, *Mas Théot.*,1945, p. 343).
>
> Ac.9 (livrer)
>  ★I. V. tr.
>  [...]
>  ☆3. Exposer, abandonner,
>   soumettre à l'action, aux effets de quelque chose. [...] • Fig. *Je
>   livre ces quelques phrases à votre méditation, à votre sagacité.
>   Livrer ses pensées, ses espoirs, ses impressions,* les faire
>   connaître, les révéler.
>
> [ Extraits des dictionnaires en question ]

Comment: Vraiment loufoque de voir qu'on a fait -1 gratuitement là-dessus. C'est d'un anti-intellectualisme rampant.

Answer (score 1):

Le verbe « confier »  implique les notion suivantes (TLFi) et il n'a pas de véritable sens figuré reconnu.

> CONFIER, verbe trans.
>   **A. Remettre quelqu'un ou quelque chose à la garde, aux soins d'une personne dont on est sûr**
>    **[Le compl. désigne un objet, un animal à garder]** 
>    **[Le compl. désigne un objet propre à assumer une tâche, des objets dont on s'occupe]**
>  
>    **[Le compl. désigne une tâche, une responsabilité]**
>   **Emploi pronom. [Le compl. ne désigne pas une pers., un objet, une abstraction]**
>   **P. anal. Livrer à l'action, à l'influence de quelque chose.** C'étaient de bons fellahs, qui possédaient (...) un peu de cette terre noire qui rend au centuple le grain qu'on lui confie (A. FRANCE, La Vie littér., t. 3, 1891, p. 131). Meyerbeer, Rossini, Verdi lui ont confié [au piano] les premières inspirations de leurs chefs-d'œuvre (G. HUBERSON, Nouveau manuel complet de l'accordeur et du réparateur de pianos, 1926, p. 3).
>   **B. Faire part à quelqu'un de sentiments intimes ou d'informations confidentielles**
>   SYNT. Confier ses angoisses, ses espoirs, ses inquiétudes, ses peines, ses rêves, ses scrupules, ses soucis, ses tourments à qqn; confier qqc. dans, à l'oreille de qqn.

On voit qu'il ne s'agit pas du sens « B » ni de la plus grande partie du sens « A » mais de la partie « par analogie » du sens « A », quasiment un sens figuré; le sens « livrer à l'influence de qqc » est même très apte.

Il n'y a pas de principe qui prévoit que l'utilisation des deux acceptions avec le terme « impression » ne soit pas possible. Il n'est évidemment pas question de sentiments intimes ou d'information confidentielles dans l'exemple no° 2 ci-dessous, ni dans l'usage en ce qui concerne l'acte de livrer un discours.

- Hélène savait que parler à n'importe qui risquait de compromettre la situation de sa camarade, mais elle devait prendre conseil au vu de ce qu'elle avait appris; elle en arriva à penser que sa mère comprendrait et se tairait et elle lui confia ses craintes.
- En tant que collaborateur de Monsieur l'administrateur Jean Perlier lui a confié ses craintes concernant les prochains changements; voici comment cela a modifié les vues de Monsieur l'administrateur.

Donc, la réponse est apparemment « oui » avec cette réserve que les objets directs qui sont des noms  tels que « secret » ne font pas partie de la définition, comme ils est alors question d'information confidentielle.

Comment: Ai-je mal compris votre réponse... dites-vous que puisque le verbe livrer peut avoir le sens de confier, que vous dites alors qu'on peut s'appuyer sur les collocations employées avec le verbe confier qui cadreraient avec discours pour dire qu'on peut utiliser discours avec livrer dans le sens de confier ?? Qu'en est-il de la deuxième partie de la question, soit celle touchant le sens de « faire connaître, révéler ». Je vous invite svp. à vous appuyez sur des exemples réels d'emploi et non sur des créations de votre cru...

Comment: @subsexdexter Ma justification aurait dû être plus explicite ; c'est à peu près ce que j'entrevois ; de plus une collocation comme « livrer des phrases », les phrases n'étant que les constituants du discours, me semble suffire à reconnaitre le bien fondé de cette possibilité. Je ne crois pas m'appuyer sur une création de mon cru mais sur un raisonnement : puisque la possibilité est clairement admise par une autorité en la matière pour un concept donné il ne doit pas y avoir de limite ; penser autrement équivaudrait à vouloir un verbe pour chaque concept voisin ; (champ  1)

Comment: @subsexdexter On dit « Je vous livre ces phrases. », donc on doit pouvoir dire « Je vous livre ces mots, ces pensées, ces déductions, ce discours, etc. ». Un point de désaccord : « confier »  qu'au sens figuré et « révéler » au sens propre, « livrer »  toujours pris au sens figuré. Pas d'exemples mais un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=livrer+un+discours%2Clivrer+ses+pens%C3%A9es&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clivrer%20un%20discours%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clivrer%20ses%20pens%C3%A9es%3B%2Cc0) montre  non négligeable. (fin)

Comment: Pour les _créations de votre cru_ on se comprend mal, je parle simplement de vos exemples avec Hélène et Jean Perlier. Je cherche des exemples réels avec _livrer un discours_ avec les emplois dont nous discutons...

Answer (score 1):

Comme je l'ai écrit [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33748/livrer-un-discours-au-propre-pour-prononcer-un-discours-est-il-un-empl), *livrer* dans le sens de *confier* et *discours* dans le sens d'*allocution* sont incompatibles, antinomiques.

En revanche, *livrer un discours* dans le sens *faire connaitre ses propos*, sans qu'il soit question de prise de parole face à une assemblée, est possible mais rare.

L'anglicisme de la tournure ne fait cependant guère de doute quand on observe à travers Google Ngrams la sur-représentation du Canada francophone dans les ouvrages l'utilisant.